# Calling a function that is apart of an initialized object after a member variable has changed in another file

Tags: c++, qt

Pretty much this window opens up and asks for a bandname. I got it so the characters on the line edit widget get stored in a variable. Problem is I have another file called main window.cpp and I want that variable to to be stored on the list widget on that window. Now I know how to display things on the list widget but I can't figure out a way to get the text after the user finished typing. The bandname var in the main window.cpp file just takes an empty string and I know why but is there any way to trigger the get call after the user has finished typing. Do I have to restrict something in the class like the get function. I've experimented a lot and saw callbacks but I could just use signals and slots. Everything Ive tried just returns an empty string but I need the text after the user has finished typing what he wants. Here is the dialog window named add button

```
#include "addbutton.h"
#include "ui_addbutton.h"
AddButton::AddButton(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::AddButton)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->cancel,SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(close()));

    //Get Text when user presses enter
    connect(ui->lineEdit, SIGNAL(editingFinished()),this,SLOT(setBandName()));

}
void AddButton::setBandName(){

    bandname = ui->lineEdit->text();

}

void AddButton::updateState(){
    pbandname = bandname;

}

QString AddButton::getBandName(){
    return bandname;
 }

AddButton::~AddButton()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Here is the main window.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "addbutton.h"
#include "bandinfo.h"
#include "QDebug"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)

{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mediaplayer = new Player;
    connect(ui->pushbutton_addBand,SIGNAL(pressed()),this,SLOT(addBand()));



}
void MainWindow::addBand(){
    BandInfo band;
    AddButton *addband_window = new AddButton;
    QString bandname;

    addband_window->show();

    bandname = addband_window->pbandname;

    qDebug() << bandname;
} 
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your post.  Are you saying you want the main window to be notified/updated when the user finishes editing in the "AddButton" class?

If I've got that right it seems pretty straightforward:

1. Add a signal to the AddButton class.  Call it something like "bandNameChanged".
2. Make the signal pass a string as its argument
3. Emit the signal from within AddButton::setBandName and pass the string name.
4. Have the main window connect a slot to the "bandNameChanged" signal when it creates the AddButton.
5. In the slot, update your list widget

Comment: Thanks man now I have another way to think about this never really used emit before. However for some reason it the signal and slots work perfectly when theres no arguments for the functions being used. As soon as I put the string argument in it can't find the signal saying no such signal any tips?